# Random new line when reading rs232

Tags: java, serial-port, newline

I'm working on a java program that writes commands and reads output of a thermometer through rs232. 
I'm using [JSSC](https://code.google.com/p/java-simple-serial-connector/). The writing part works fine, but when I'm reading the output and convert it to String and print it with System.out.println(), some random new lines appear. When I write the result with  System.out.write(), everything is working fine.
I checked the bytecode, and I didn't found any NL character.

Heres my code:

```
public boolean openPort(int rate, int databits, int stopbit, int parity){
    try {
        serialPort.openPort();
        serialPort.setParams(rate, databits, stopbit, parity);
        int mask = SerialPort.MASK_RXCHAR + SerialPort.MASK_CTS + SerialPort.MASK_DSR;//Prepare mask
        serialPort.setEventsMask(mask);//Set mask
        serialPort.addEventListener(new SerialPortReader());//Add SerialPortEventListener

        return true;
    } catch (SerialPortException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        return false;
    }
}

 static class SerialPortReader implements SerialPortEventListener {

    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
        if(event.isRXCHAR()){//If data is available
                try {
                    byte buffer[] = serialPort.readBytes(event.getEventValue());    
//with system.out.write
                    try {
                        System.out.write(buffer);

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
//with system.out.println                       
                    String readed = new String(buffer);
                    System.out.println(readed);
                }
                catch (SerialPortException ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex);
                }
        }
        else if(event.isCTS()){//If CTS line has changed state
            if(event.getEventValue() == 1){//If line is ON
                System.out.println("CTS - ON");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("CTS - OFF");
            }
        }
        else if(event.isDSR()){///If DSR line has changed state
            if(event.getEventValue() == 1){//If line is ON
                System.out.println("DSR - ON");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("DSR - OFF");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the outpout with println():

```
--- START (C) ---

21.0,
21.1,21.3,
21.1

21.0,
21.2,21.3,
21.2
```

And the desired output with write()

```
--- START (C) ---
21.0,21.1,21.3,21.1
21.0,21.1,21.3,21.1
```

You'll say "why don't you just use write()?", but I need to convert this output to a string.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Is the thermometer in your desired output sending the newlines after 4 values?  You say its desired output, but you're wondering in a comment to Hot Licks answer that you're not expecting a newline, I'm confused.

Comment: Yeah,I might have explained it badly... I want to have a new line after 4 values. But when I'm using println(),  there's new lines everywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`println` adds a newline character at the end.  To not add that, use `print`.

Comment: I forgot to test with print()... But why are my Strings not the same length?

Comment: Your strings aren't the same length because in one case the device manages to send two readings between "events", so you do only one println for both of them.

Comment: Try creating a string from the byte buffer you get, and trimming it.  You might be reading unpredictable data, a well-formatted string over serial is rare and a godsend.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue recently.
Recently I started some research on reading my Smart energy meter with my Pi.
I came across JSSC and decided to give it a try.
But I After many hours of trying to get it rid of these unwanted newlines, I switched over to RXTX.
This works like a charm now.

See http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

Below is some early code from this project. 
Hope this helps.

```
package nl.barendregtict.homeautomation;

import gnu.io.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.TooManyListenersException;

/**
 * Created by sbarendr on 09/11/14.
 */
public class KaifaSmartMeterReader implements SerialPortEventListener {

    CommPortIdentifier portId1;
    SerialPort serialPort1;
    InputStream inputStream;
    Thread readThread;


    public KaifaSmartMeterReader() {
        try {
            portId1 = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier("/dev/ttyUSB0");
            serialPort1 = (SerialPort) portId1.open("KaifaSmartMeterReader", 2000);
            System.out.println(portId1.getName() + " opened");
            inputStream = serialPort1.getInputStream();
            serialPort1.addEventListener(this);
            serialPort1.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
            serialPort1.setSerialPortParams(115200,
                    SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                    SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                    SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
            serialPort1.setDTR(false);
            serialPort1.setRTS(false);
            Thread.sleep(30000);
            serialPort1.close();
        } catch (
                PortInUseException
                | IOException
                | TooManyListenersException
                | UnsupportedCommOperationException
                | InterruptedException
                | NoSuchPortException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
        switch(event.getEventType()) {
            case SerialPortEvent.BI:
            case SerialPortEvent.OE:
            case SerialPortEvent.FE:
            case SerialPortEvent.PE:
            case SerialPortEvent.CD:
            case SerialPortEvent.CTS:
            case SerialPortEvent.DSR:
            case SerialPortEvent.RI:
            case SerialPortEvent.OUTPUT_BUFFER_EMPTY:
                break;
            case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE:
                StringBuffer readBuffer = new StringBuffer();
                int c;
                try {
                    while ((c = inputStream.read()) != 10) {
                        if (c != 13) readBuffer.append((char) c);
                    }
                    String scannedInput = readBuffer.toString();
                    System.out.println(scannedInput);
                }
                catch(IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            KaifaSmartMeterReader reader = new KaifaSmartMeterReader();
    }
}
```